# Cannot get RoundRobinScheduler to work in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

I'm running with Cassandra 2.1.16. I have a need to limit the number of queries to a specific keyspace in Cassandra because the application is running a query for that keyspace that is memory intensive. If enough of these run at the same time, Cassandra will run out of heap.

Using the RoundRobinScheduler seems like the ideal solution for this. So I enabled it in cassandra.yaml, and set the request_scheduler_options. So for my example below, I want no more than 2 queries active at once for the keyspace called mykeyspace:

```
request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.RoundRobinScheduler
request_scheduler_options:
  throttle_limit: 80
  default_weight: 5
  weights: mykeyspace: 2
request_scheduler_id: keyspace
```

This does not work and has no effect. To debug this, I downloaded the Cassandra source and added debug log messages to all of the methods in the RoundRobinScheduler class. The only messages logged are from the constructor. I don't see log messages from the other methods when I run queries.

Has anyone had any luck using RoundRobinScheduler? Perhaps I've misunderstood the use of this scheduler.

Comment: I don't think this will help you. Throttling down your instance is never a good idea. You should partition your data better and limit the scan queries that come in from the clients. Be sure you are not using row caches etc. Also check for tombstones. Don't work your way around the base problem this won't get easier as your application grows. By looking at your question you seem to know your way around enough to check for this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered looking at the 2.1.16 Cassandra source code that this query rate limiting mechanism only applies to the Thrift protocol. It does not apply to the CQL3 protocol. When I ran a query through Cassandra's deprecated command-cli (which is the raw Thrift interpreter), I do see the debug messages which I instrumented in the RoundRobinScheduler class.

What I don't know is if this query rate limiting mechanism has since been adapted to CQL3. My project is using the relatively old 2.1 release. The parameters are still contained in the cassandra.yaml distributed in the 3.9 release. Some time I'll have to download the source and see for myself.

Comment: Did you check in 3.9 release ? Please updated if you have anything on this.